# Find Longest Increasing Subsequence with adjacent elements having a difference increasing along the subarray

Tags: dynamic-programming

this dynamic programming question is very similar to this form of question
"Find Longest Increasing Subsequence with adjacent elements having a difference of at least k"

But instead of a constant difference of k, the k should be increasing along the array.
For example, 1,2,5,10 is a valid subsequence as the difference between elements is 1,3,5 which is increasing.

But 1,2,5,20,21 is invalid as the difference between elements are 1,3,15,1 which is not increasing.